# Is God Grateful?

Tags: nature-of-god, divine-characteristics

I realize the gravity of what I'm asking. But, is God grateful? Does God have a thankful attitude toward his creation? God is gracious, but is he filled with a sense of gratitude in this graciousness?

Is the Biblical idea of grace found in this idea of gratitude and gratefulness and thanksgiving?

I'll provide a few verses that seem to be in context and show God has a hint of gratitude to humans:

- Isaiah 66:2: God the Son was thankful to God the Father:

  > For all those things My hand has made,
  > And all those things exist,”
  > Says the LORD.
  > “But to this one will I look:
  > On him who is poor and of a contrite spirit,
  > And who trembles at My word.
- Luke 1:48a:

  > For He has regarded the lowly state of His maidservant;
- Luke 10:21:

  > At that time he rejoiced in the Holy Spirit and said, “I openly acknowledge you, Father, Lord of heaven and earth, because you have hidden these things from the wise and intelligent and revealed them to infants. Yes, Father, because this was your good pleasure.
- Psalm 138:6:

  > Though the Lord is on high,
  > Yet He regards the lowly;
  > But the proud He knows from a distance.
- Hebrews 11:6:

  > Now without faith it is impossible to please God, since the one who draws near to him must believe that he exists and that he **rewards** those who seek him.
- Proverbs 3:34:

  > He mocks those who mock but shows favor to the humble.
- Genesis 6:8:

  > But, Noah found favor in the eyes of the LORD.

Comment: @Peter I've rolled back your edit as I don't think this is really a Biblical Basis question - it would need to present evidence that there is some group of Christians who teach that God is grateful for this to be a Biblical Basis question. It could be closed as a truth question, but I think most Christians would actually be pretty consistent in their answer so I'm happy for this question to stay open.

Comment: @curiousdannii, would you explain why you would change my edits? I just added a couple of more scriptures and pointed out Jesus, the Son of God, showed thankfulness.

Comment: You can see the [edit history here](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/posts/93050/revisions). We didn't really change any of your edits. What I reverted was Peter's change to the question title - now it's back to how it was originally.

Comment: @curiousdannii, oh. Thank you!

Comment: There is  problem with the question here. If you want to know if God is grateful, you'll have to ask Him.

Answer (score 3):

> Oh, the depth of the riches and wisdom and knowledge of God! How unsearchable are his judgments and how inscrutable his ways! “For who has known the mind of the Lord, or who has been his counselor?” “Or who has given a gift to him that he might be repaid?” For from him and through him and to him are all things. To him be glory forever. Amen. - Romans 11:33-36

It is interesting that the words grateful or gratitude, seldom appear in the Bible.  When they do appear in certain translations they translate a word that is usually translated as grace.  Interesting also is that "gratitude" is never used in place of "grace" when the grace in view is God's grace.  It is only used when viewing our response to God's lovingkindness toward us.  Therefore, I think a distinction needs to be made between God being pleased *with* His creation:

> And God saw everything that he had made, and behold, it was very good. - Genesis 1:31

and God being grateful *to* His creation.  His [immutability](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/immutability/) affords some theological ground for this distinction.

If God is immutable, that is if He cannot be changed in any real, intrinsic way, then for God to be grateful He must have always been grateful or possessed the capacity for gratefulness even prior to creation.  At some point in eternity (if such a phrase makes any sense) prior to the creation of heaven and earth when there was just God, to what or whom would He have been grateful?  Can self-existence be grateful to itself for anything?  I suggest the answer is no.

If God, in this eternal state, had an unfulfilled or unexercised capacity for gratefulness then it must be argued that He created in order to satisfy some lack within Himself; that He created so that He could express something that He needed or wanted to express but could not.

This is because gratefulness is a response.  Unlike the love of God, which is unmerited and uni-directional, gratefulness is a response to "benefits received" which indicates a fulfilled lack within the grateful party.  One cannot be grateful unless one receives something *from another* that one did not and possibly could not have alone.  The Cambridge dictionary defines grateful as:

> showing or expressing thanks, especially to another person

I suggest, then, that gratefulness is unique to the creation as a response to the creator and that, while God may be pleased with His children ("Well done good and faithful servant", "pleasing aroma of sacrifice", etc), He cannot benefit or be added unto by them in a way that could elicit gratefulness.

The over-riding tenor of Scripture bids us beware of thinking so highly of ourselves that we could add to Deity:

> “Will any one of you who has a servant plowing or keeping sheep say to him when he has come in from the field, ‘Come at once and recline at table’? Will he not rather say to him, ‘Prepare supper for me, and dress properly, and serve me while I eat and drink, and afterward you will eat and drink’? Does he thank the servant because he did what was commanded? So you also, when you have done all that you were commanded, say, ‘We are unworthy servants; we have only done what was our duty.’” - Luke 17:7-10

Comment: Thanks Mike. A few things: 1. Humans are made in God's image. 2. Because humans did not meet God's expectations, he felt deep pain (Genesis 6:6). 3. The prophets expressed God's disappointment, his sorrow, his anger, his deep feelings. 4. Jesus expressed disappointment, approval, disgust, delight - all in relationship to those around him and "he who seen me has seen the Father" (also see Hebrews 1:3, Colossians 1:19).  So...based upon a few other points of view on this subject, as well as citing my examples above, God delights in some people and rejects others. Is he thankful for us?

Comment: One other thing, in Matthew 13 Jesus spoke of a pearl of great price. It looks like God is quite able to seek beautiful things out in his own mind and thereby create that beauty. So, he appreciates. How close is appreciation to gratefulness, when some of his creation actually pays attention to him rather than lives like God doesn't exist? Or maybe you would say this is too much like people? But, then where do people get these qualities, if not from the Creator himself who made us in HIS image? Anyway...interesting subject. Convinced we don't know, because scripture doesn't say God is grateful.

Comment: Thankfulness is directed otherward. To whom would God be thankful for His creation. " when some of his creation actually pays attention to him rather than lives like God doesn't exist" I would say that He is pleased because that is what is best for us and He loves us and wants the best for us but, ultimately, that is mere obedience on our part.  Is He grateful when we obey ...  when we do what we were created to do?   At the judgement seat, will He thank us?

Comment: He will reward us from what I've read (1 Cor. 3, Revelation, in much of Jesus' teaching like Luke 12:31-33). God shows appreciation in many places, including the few verses I posted above. I really would like scripture where God says, "Thanks," but rather see in his actions he appreciates some and will dispose of the rest. Those "some" have distinct qualities. "God gives grace to the humble." "I openly acknowledge you Father..." and Jesus explained this difference. Thanks Mike. Unless I found a distinct scripture outside of what I've shown here showing God saying, "Thank you," I'm fine. Thanks

Answer (score -2):

Let's start with a definition. Merriam-Webster defines "grateful" as

> a: appreciative of benefits received
>
> b: expressing gratitude

This immediately made me think of God's response to Noah's offering:

> Noah built an altar to the Lord and took of every clean animal and of
> every clean bird and offered burnt offerings on the altar. And when
> the Lord smelled the pleasing odor, the Lord said in his heart, “I
> will never again curse the ground because of humans, for the
> inclination of the human heart is evil from youth; nor will I ever
> again destroy every living creature as I have done. (Gen. 8:20-22)

It seems to me both attitudes are expressed here. God appreciates the benefit of the sacrifice, which produces a "pleasing odor" for him, and he expresses his gratitude to Noah by promising never to curse the ground again. a
A few lines later God expresses his appreciation to Noah by giving him the sign of the rainbow and blessing his family.

**Mutual gratitude**

Yes, God is grateful. We are created in God's image and God encourages us to be grateful. It stands to reason that God would not encourage positive attributes from us that God does not also possess. He wants us to be good because he is good. He wants us to love him because he loves us. He wants us to be grateful and he returns gratitude to us when we please him. When we forgive others, he forgives us and appreciates that we act as he does.

The biblical concept of mercy/lovingkindness implies mutuality. The Hebrew term here is *chesed*. for example:

> For the mountains may move And the hills be shaken, but my *chesed*
> shall never move from you, nor My covenant of friendship be shaken —
> said YHWH, who takes you back in love. (Isa 54:10)

God's gratitude to humans is expressed in scriptures such as some of those quoted in the OP and many others.

- In Genesis 1, God expresses satisfaction toward his creation by declaring "it is good" after each day, and "it is very good" after the creation of man and woman. He expressed his gratitude at finally seeing his image reflected in Adam and Eve by richly blessing to be fruitful, fill the earth and have dominion over all things of creation.
- After Noah successfully completed the ark and guides his family through the Flood Judgement, God similarly declared his gratitude by blessing him and his family.

> God blessed Noah and his sons and said to them, “Be fruitful and
> multiply and fill the earth... Every moving thing that lives shall be
> food for you, and just as I gave you the green plants, I give you
> everything.

- When the Israelite kingdom was established, God expressed his gratitude for David: "I have found David, son of Jesse, to be a man after my heart, who will carry out all my wishes." (Acts 13:22)
- In the Parable of the Talents, Jesus portrays the master as grateful to his servant: ‘Well done, good and faithful servant! You have been faithful with a few things; I will put you in charge of many things. Come and share your master’s happiness!’ (Mt. 26)

In the parable of the Prodigal Son, the father expresses his gratitude for the son's return by blessing him with rich gift. This shows that God is deeply grateful when sinners repent and return to his embrace. As Jesus said in Luke 15:10 "I tell you, there will be more joy in heaven over one sinner who repents than over ninety-nine righteous persons who need no repentance."

**Blessings are an expression of gratitude**

One could go on an on: We are told literally dozens of times that our offerings produce a "pleasing odor" to the Lord. God is appreciates when we reflect his attributes such as goodness, trustworthiness, integrity, purity, righteousness and loving-kindness. God is our Father, who naturally wants to thank us when we return his love. God blesses us when we please him because it his nature (as it is ours) to respond in gratitude to acts and attitudes that reflect his heart as a parent. Jesus taught the beatitudes to demonstrate this.

**God's desire for a loving relationship with humans is expressed many times throughout the Bible.  When a person's love is returned with kindness, joy and gratitude result. Indeed, we may even see the purpose of God's creation as achieving a mutual relationship of joy and gratitude with mankind. God expresses his gratitude do us by giving us blessings.**

Comment: I can see the inference and see his quick and kind response in how he treats those who humbly come to him...yet the scriptures are not distinctly clear. This is sort of a dilemma for someone to find clarity in this concept of God's character and heart. Thanks for joining the conversation, nevertheless.

Comment: It feels very wrong to say that God would ever be grateful to us for anything, as if there were anything we had to offer Him that He has not already given to us. Does He rejoice when we turn to him, away from our sin? Of course. And he shows mercy and lovingkindess, as you say. But the word "grateful" has implications that I don't think are right to use here.

Comment: #Isaac, I do wonder...his kind heart in Genesis 6:6 was hurt by us, which brings me to this question of a gratefulness for those who do turn and trust him. I see why say this, since the scriptures nowhere show this, if not for what we see in Jesus. He showed gratitude to the Father. Did Jesus ever show gratitude or thank anyone for anything? Hmmm. I can't think of one time, can you?

Comment: Another thing I do wonder, too, when Jesus strengthened the faith of the apostles at their request , he illustrated that the servant is not thanked for doing what he had been commanded. "In the same way, when you have done everything that has been arranged and ordered for you, you should say, ‘We are unworthy servants; we’ve only done our duty.’" (from Luke 17)

Comment: I'm going to add a bit to my answer,  starting with a definition of grateful

Comment: @RobCallicotte... Jesus thanked the Father, and the Father (in my opinion) is grateful to Jesus. As I've argued above, when God blesses us, he is expressing his gratitude to us.